# How to invalidate tag across-api in RTK query

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit

I wanted to split the API into two parts, but the provided tag endpoint didn't refetch itself, when the invalidatesTag endpoint at the other part was called.
BaseApi:

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react";
export const baseApi = createApi({
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: `${import.meta.env.VITE_SERVER}` }),
  tagTypes: ["Cart", "Shopping", "Product"],
  endpoints: () => ({}),
});
```

CartApi:

```
import { baseApi } from "../BaseApi/baseApi";
type CartItemType = {
  product_id?: string;
  quantity?: number;
};
type CartType = {
  _id: string;
} & CartItemType;
type CartResponse = {
  message: string;
  data: CartType;
};

export const cartApi = baseApi.injectEndpoints({
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getCartByProDuctId: builder.query<CartResponse, string>({
      query: (id: string) => `cart-item/${id}`,
      providesTags: ["Cart"],
    }),
    createCart: builder.mutation<CartResponse, CartItemType>({
      query: (data: CartItemType) => ({
        url: "/cart-item/create",
        method: "PUT",
        body: data,
      }),
    }),
    updateCart: builder.mutation<CartResponse, CartItemType>({
      query: (data: CartItemType) => ({
        url: "/cart-item/update",
        method: "PATCH",
        body: data,
        invalidatesTags: ["Shopping"],
      }),
    }),
    deleteCart: builder.mutation<CartResponse, CartItemType>({
      query: (data: CartItemType) => ({
        url: "/cart-item/delete",
        method: "DELETE",
        body: data,
      }),
    }),
  }),
});
export const {
  useGetCartByProDuctIdQuery,
  useCreateCartMutation,
  useUpdateCartMutation,
  useDeleteCartMutation,
} = cartApi;
```

ShoppingApi:

```
import { baseApi } from "../BaseApi/baseApi";
import type { ProductType } from "../ProductReducer/ProductApi";
type cart_item = {
  product_id: ProductType;
  quantity: number;
};
type ShoppingSessionType = {
  cart_items: cart_item[];
  user_id?: string;
};
type shoppingType = {
  id: string;
  CartItemId: string;
};
export const shoppingApi = baseApi.injectEndpoints({
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getShoppingSession: builder.query<ShoppingSessionType, string>({
      query: (id: string) => `shopping/${id}`,
      providesTags: ["Shopping"],
    }),

    updateCartItem: builder.mutation<ShoppingSessionType, shoppingType>({
      query: ({ id, CartItemId }: shoppingType) => ({
        url: `shopping/update-cart-item/${id}`,
        method: "PATCH",
        body: { CartItemId },
      }),
      invalidatesTags: ["Shopping"],
    }),
    updateDeleteCartItem: builder.mutation<ShoppingSessionType, shoppingType>({
      query: ({ id, CartItemId }: shoppingType) => ({
        url: `shopping/update-delete/${id}`,
        method: "PATCH",
        body: { CartItemId },
      }),
    }),
  }),
});
export const {
  useGetShoppingSessionQuery,
  useUpdateCartItemMutation,
  useUpdateDeleteCartItemMutation,
} = shoppingApi;
```

My store setup:

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import AuthReducer from "../api/AuthReducer/AuthReduce";
import { AuthMiddleware } from "../middleware/AuthMiddleware";
import { combineReducers } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { setupListeners } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/query";
import { userApi } from "../api/UserApi/UserApi";
import { productApi } from "../api/ProductReducer/ProductApi";
import { paymentUserApi } from "../api/UserApi/UserPaymentApi";
import { shoppingApi } from "../api/ShoppingSessionApi/ShoppingSessionApi";
import { cartApi } from "../api/CartReducer/CartApi";
import { baseApi } from "../api/BaseApi/baseApi";
import { ErrorLogger } from "../middleware/ErrorLogger";
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  auth: AuthReducer,
  [userApi.reducerPath]: userApi.reducer,
  [productApi.reducerPath]: productApi.reducer,
  [paymentUserApi.reducerPath]: paymentUserApi.reducer,
  [baseApi.reducerPath]: baseApi.reducer,
  [cartApi.reducerPath]: cartApi.reducer,
  [shoppingApi.reducerPath]: shoppingApi.reducer,
});
export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => [
    ...getDefaultMiddleware(),
    userApi.middleware,
    productApi.middleware,
    paymentUserApi.middleware,
    baseApi.middleware,
    cartApi.middleware,
    shoppingApi.middleware,
    AuthMiddleware,
    ErrorLogger,
  ],
});
setupListeners(store.dispatch);
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof rootReducer>;
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
```

When I call the endpoint updateCart, the endpoint getShoppingSession should refetch. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found my own solution for this. The line `invalidatesTag` should be moved out of the query.

```
updateCart: builder.mutation<CartResponse, CartItemType>({
      query: (data: CartItemType) => ({
        url: "/cart-item/update",
        method: "PATCH",
        body: data,
        invalidatesTags: ["Shopping"],
      }),
    }),
```

should instead look like:

```
updateCart: builder.mutation<CartResponse, CartItemType>({
      query: (data: CartItemType) => ({
        url: "/cart-item/update",
        method: "PATCH",
        body: data,
      }),
        invalidatesTags: ["Shopping"],
    }),
```

Answer (score 0):

Only add your `baseApi` to your store - this is all the same api, just with more endpoints every time. You are essentially adding the same middleware 6 times.

```js
export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    auth: AuthReducer,
    [baseApi.reducerPath]: userApi.reducer,
  },
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => 
    getDefaultMiddleware()
    .concat(baseApi.middleware)
    .concat(AuthMiddleware)
    .concat(ErrorLogger)
});
```

Comment: I tried, but it still is, my solution is to use refetch, forcing it to refetch, however, it makes me feel that this solution is defeating the ideology of code splitting

Comment: As the author of RTK Query I can tell you that all these 6 apis are the same api and if they are injected into the same `baseApi` there is literally no difference having them in different files or in the same file. Are you 100% sure it worked before and you did not change anything?

Comment: I changed it exactly what you did, but it still is. The invalidating tags only works, if any endpoint mutation derived from the same slice as endpoint providing tags

Comment: I am 100% certain that if you copy those into the same api you will have the same result. There is *one* possibility: if you are working with persisted data, and you invalidate something before you actually import the other file with the affected api endpoints, those "won't be there", so they can also not be invalidated. But since you don't show any persistence code, that's probably not it.

Comment: I tried copy all endpoints from cartApi to shoppingApi, but turned out, it didn't working at all. Maybe the problem is all the endpoints in shoppingApi have their queries beginning from "/shopping/" and in cartApi starting from "/cart-item/"

Comment: No, it's nothing of the likes. Tags have nothing to do with anything else in there. Did you maybe use the wrong tags or forgot a `providesTags` or `invalidatesTags` somewhere?

Comment: that's strange, even though in same slice all endpoint mutation come from cartApi do not invalidate tags

Comment: no, i had checked I didn't forget anything

Comment: https://github.com/maikusobu/ShopMaikusobu/tree/main/client/src/api here is my entire api code, if it could help you help me to figure it out :)), I'm kinda newbie, and working in this project as practice

Comment: You already have the code up there, but you don't say which one doesn't refetch when which one finishes.

Comment: I had, I wrote at the end "When I call the endpoint updateCart, the endpoint getShoppingSession should refetch. Thank you for your help" 
when useUpdateCartMutation finishes,  useGetShoppingSessionQuery should refetch

Comment: Argh, sorry. Tbh., I don't see something really wrong here. Have you validated in your network tab that it is not indeed refetching? It won't go back to `isLoading`, only to `isFetching`.